# Using VBA, is there a way to look up a cell based on criteria for two columns (similar to Index Match formula)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing, match

I'm trying to figure out the best way to lookup cell information based on criteria for two columns. For example, I have column A with one set of numbers, column B with another set of numbers, and column C with the cell information I want to extract. The cell info must match the Column A & Column B info I give in a user form, and then when I click 'Search' I want the userform to populate with Column C's info. The userform coding is fine-I'm just having trouble with the 'lookup' aspect. If I were to write this code not in vba and just as an array, it would look like so:

```
={INDEX(A1:C20,MATCH(1,(A:A=ColumnAItem)*(B:B=ColumnBItem),0),3)}
```

And this is basically what I've figured out on my own so far in VBA:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

Dim SAP_A As Variant, SAP_B As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet, mA, mB


Set ws = Sheets("Database Entry Sheet")


SAP_A = Trim(textbox5.Value)
SAP_B = Trim(textbox8.Value)

    mA = Application.Match(CLng(SAP_A), ws.Range("A:A"), 0)
    mB = Application.Match(CLng(SAP_B), ws.Range("B:B"), 0)

    If Not IsError(mA) And IsError(mB) Then
        textbox1.Text = ws.Cells(mA, "C")

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the information in column C a number or text?

Comment: It varies for the greater spreadsheet, but generally a number

Comment: Is there always only *one* row corresponding to the combination of `SAP_A` and `SAP_B`? Also, seems like you're missing a `Not` in front of `IsError(mB)`.

Comment: It's probably easier to loop through a Variant array here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

Dim SAP_A As Variant, SAP_B As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet, mA, mB


Set ws = Sheets("Database Entry Sheet")


SAP_A = Trim(textbox5.Value)
SAP_B = Trim(textbox8.Value)

    mA = Application.Match(CLng(SAP_A), ws.Range("A:A"), 0)
    mB = Application.Match(CLng(SAP_B), ws.Range("B:B"), 0)
    
    '* Added Not before IsError(mB)
    If Not IsError(mA) And Not IsError(mB) Then
        '* Make sure they correspond to the same row
        If mA = mB Then   
            textbox1.Text = ws.Cells(mA, "C")
        End If
    End If '* End the if statement
End Sub
```

Note my comments starting with `'*`

There's however a subtle **problem** with the logic here if values are repeated on the same column: Take this example

```
A  B  C
1  2  V1
5  1  V2
9  4  V3
3  1  V4
2  7  V5
```

Now if the user searches for `SAP_A = 3` and `SAP_B = 1` then `mA = 4` and `mB = 2` and the code therefore, is not going to give you `V4` as you would expect. This is because `Match` gives you the index of the first matched value. Therefore, if you have repeated values in either column, then it is better to loop down columns A and B and check if both values match and return the value in column C. (**Edit:** or even better, read the whole range into a variant array and therefore, loop in memory rather a range: as @BigBen suggested in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

    Dim A As Variant, B As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, f, m

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    A = "B"
    B = "F"

    'Note: whether or not you need quotes in the formula around
    '  A and B will depend on the expected datatypes
    f = "=(A1:A20=""{A}"")*(B1:B20=""{B}"")"
    f = Replace(f, "{A}", A)
    f = Replace(f, "{B}", B)
    Debug.Print f
    
    m = Application.Match(1, ws.Evaluate(f), 0)
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        Debug.Print ws.Cells(m, "C")
    Else
        Debug.Print "no match for", A, B
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is awesome-thank you! How does the A=B and B = F play into the code? I'm just confused what the B and F are used for

Comment: Those are just dummy values I was using in testing - to show the basic principles of matching two values "A" and "B"